# PostgreSQL Performance check

Tags: postgresql

I have heard PostgreSQL being used in cases where the tables run into billion of rows and having satisfactory response times too. But here's my simple experiment to check this out. I have a table with 6 columns and has **4255700** entries exactly. I have used pgtune to tune the configuration according to my setup. Now, when I run a simple "*select * from tab1*", it is taking **173.425** seconds to fetch all the rows. Is this the normal behavior? I have this single table in the DB.

The table definition is as follows -

```
CREATE TABLE file_group_permissions
(
  fgp_id serial NOT NULL,
  file_id integer NOT NULL,
  pg_id integer NOT NULL,
  policy_id integer,
  tag_id integer,
  inst_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT file_group_permissions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (fgp_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE file_group_permissions
  OWNER TO sa;

-- Index: fgp_file_idx

-- DROP INDEX fgp_file_idx;

CREATE INDEX fgp_file_idx
  ON file_group_permissions
  USING btree
  (file_id);
ALTER TABLE file_group_permissions CLUSTER ON fgp_file_idx;

-- Index: fgp_inst_idx

-- DROP INDEX fgp_inst_idx;

CREATE INDEX fgp_inst_idx
  ON file_group_permissions
  USING btree
  (inst_id);

-- Index: fgp_tag_idx

-- DROP INDEX fgp_tag_idx;

CREATE INDEX fgp_tag_idx
  ON file_group_permissions
  USING btree
  (tag_id);

-- Index: pgfgp_idx

-- DROP INDEX pgfgp_idx;

CREATE INDEX pgfgp_idx
  ON file_group_permissions
  USING btree
  (pg_id);
```

Output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select * from file_group_permissions -

```
"Seq Scan on file_group_permissions  (cost=0.00..69662.00 rows=4255700 
width=24) (actual time=0.019..580.273 rows=4255700 loops=1)"

"  Buffers: shared hit=2432 read=24673"

"Planning time: 0.070 ms"

"Execution time: 903.325 ms"
```

I have a MacBook Pro with 16 Gigs of RAM and 512 Gigs of SSD. I have configured the PostgreSQL to use 2Gigs of RAM.

**Edit**

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select pg_id, count(distinct file_id) from file_group_permissions where pg_id in (6117,6115,6116,6113,6114) group by 1;


"GroupAggregate  (cost=0.44..102028.21 rows=208 width=8) (actual time=4970.884..5013.423 rows=3 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: pg_id"
"  Buffers: shared hit=50891, temp read=4824 written=4824"
"  ->  Index Scan using pgfgp_idx on file_group_permissions (cost=0.44..85511.31 rows=3302964 width=8) (actual time=0.062..1080.926 rows=3323389 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (pg_id = ANY('{6117,6115,6116,6113,6114}'::integer[]))"
"        Buffers: shared hit=50891"
"Planning time: 0.219 ms"
"Execution time: 5013.495 ms"
```

**EDIT1**

I separated this table into a new DB and followed the suggestions (composite indices and postgresql conf), here's the new plan -

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=478307.10..502996.67 rows=209 width=8) (actual 
time=7500.426..7528.021 rows=3 loops=1)"


"  Group Key: pg_id"

"  Buffers: shared read=27105, temp read=12137 written=12137"

"  ->  Sort  (cost=478307.10..486536.26 rows=3291664 width=8) (actual 
time=2944.597..3647.248 rows=3323389 loops=1)"

"        Sort Key: pg_id"

"        Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 58488kB"

"        Buffers: shared read=27105, temp read=7311 written=7311"

"        ->  Seq Scan on file_group_permissions  (cost=0.00..96260.12 
rows=3291664 width=8) (actual time=0.016..1516.743 rows=3323389 loops=1)"


"              Filter: (pg_id = ANY 
('{6117,6115,6116,6113,6114}'::integer[]))"

"              Rows Removed by Filter: 932311"

"              Buffers: shared read=27105"

"Planning time: 0.514 ms"

"Execution time: 7540.243 ms"
```

This table is simply jinxed and it is hurting the performance everywhere it is being joined.

Comment: Transferring 4255700 rows from the server to the client **will** take some time. After all that's roughly 200MB that need to be sent, received and processed (and potentially displayed) by your client software.

Comment: This question seems more suited for [dba.se].

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I understand, but 173 seconds?? There must be an answer for that.

Comment: Those could be a lot of reasons, slow network, slow client, slow harddisk. There is not enough information to be able to answer your question. Please read: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions and supply the missing information

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, for the incomplete info, I am using the local machine to do this and updated all other details.

Comment: All you are testing with this, is the performance of your SQL client. It says absolutely nothing about the performance of the Postgres server (plus: a `select * from some_table` is hardly a meaningful test in itself anyway).

Comment: Doing a "SELECT * FROM TABLE" is definitively the worst way of bench-marking a Postgres server. It tells you absolutely nothing about hardware performance or database tuning.  pgtune website is a good start, but you surely have to read more about all postgresql.conf parameters. A good example is the `random_page_cost` when your database fits entirely into RAM or when using fast SSD hard-disks.

Comment: @ChristianB.Almeida I did this preposterous benchmark test using a "select *" because I tried so many things, but queries around this table return in more than 5 seconds, included a sample query in the question. I already have the random_page_cost set to 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a test table, just like yours, and I have populated it with exactly same amount of records:

```
insert into file_group_permissions (file_id,pg_id,policy_id,tag_id,inst_id)
select 
  trunc(random()*10000) as file_id, 
  trunc(random()*10000) as pg_id, 
  trunc(random()*10000) as policy_id, 
  trunc(random()*10000) as tag_id, 
  trunc(random()*10000) as inst_id
from generate_series(1,4255700) g
```

When I run your query, it executes pretty fast:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) 
select pg_id, count(distinct file_id) 
from file_group_permissions 
where pg_id in (6117,6115,6116,6113,6114) group by 1;

GroupAggregate  (cost=0.43..8.32 rows=5 width=8) (actual time=0.339..1.608 rows=5 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=2158
  ->  Index Scan using pgfgp_idx on file_group_permissions  (cost=0.43..8.24 rows=5 width=8) (actual time=0.018..1.170 rows=2147 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (pg_id = ANY ('{6117,6115,6116,6113,6114}'::integer[]))
        Buffers: shared hit=2158
Total runtime: 1.633 ms
```

I have notice this line in your execution plan:

```
Buffers: shared hit=50891, temp read=4824 written=4824
```

`temp read=4824 written=4824` tells us that the database is "using" disk somehow to perform the scan operation. Perhaps you have to tweak some other postgresql.conf parameters, like these of mine:

```
shared_buffers       = 1GB   
temp_buffers         = 32MB
work_mem             = 32MB
effective_cache_size = 1GB
```

Comment: Posted my new results with all the suggestions in mind.

Comment: And guys, you don't have any data matching in the table, so the query is super fast.

Comment: I do have matching data. Try to cluster the table to the pg_id index.